# Pokemon Go: Is the sightings list of pokemon sorted according to distance from me?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the example below, does it mean that eevee is the closest to me, or is there any sort order?

[image: sightings]

Comment: I can't say for sure, how it's being sorted, but not by distance. It's not the first time I caught a Pokémon listed somewhere in the middle without any other popping up (so they're not close enough to catch them).

Comment: In my expirience they are not sorted by distance. Somethimes pokemon in the first and third place appear at the same time but the second one doesn't somethimes one in the middle appears or the last one. Hopefully they fix that

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I managed to verify that it is indeed not sorted according to distance.. since Slowpoke and Magikarp did not appear anywhere near me.

[image: Slowpoke is not the nearest to me]

Comment: I think it does not take exact distance but "distance categories", for example first category can be "closer than 200m", second one can be " 200 to 400m" etc. Then you can find some not listed at first place, because those in same distance category are listed by another 2nd level criteria. But even from your screenshot you can see that weedle IS close and IS in top part (thus visible) of the list in sightings. From my experience, when  I found pokémon, he normally was in top part of the list.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík Niantic debunked that function (with the footprints) shortly after release, since it never worked properly. So it might be intended to be sorted that way, but it didn't even work back when it was still there for everyone to see.

Comment: @dly I talk about new system, of course. You will more often find pokémons from top of new sightings list. Not every time the totally top one, but still one of them. Then I can imagine "distance groups" sorting.